# Weird characters when I fire Push Notification in XCode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, encoding

I'm facing a weird character when I fire local notification in Arabic. the result that it showing wrong characters as in the picture below.

[image]

Note the sentence has parceled to Arabic localization Plist file. Plist and other cpp files are encoded UTF-8... here's the code of parcelling to the Plist file

and the function of PushLocalNotif below

```
PushLocalNotif((CCLocalizedString("Notif1"), 2);


void PushLocalNotif(const char* string,int day) {
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
[notification setAlertBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",string]];
//[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*day]];
[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60/* * 60 * day*/]];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

and the localized plist file with the notif sentence.
[image]

I'm sure the wrong is something related to encoding the character but I don't find a way to encoding that sentence :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do `[notification setAlertBody: [NSString stringWithCString:string encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` instead.